# Managed package install script - sObject type not supported

Tags: apex, package, install, postinstall, managed-package

I have a managed package with a PostInstall script, however I'm having trouble accessing custom objects within it.

Apon installation, I get the following error notification email

```
System.QueryException: sObject type 'mypackage__Settings__c' is not supported.
```

The line referenced in the exception is a normal SOQL query against a custom object in the package

```
Settings__c = [SELECT Field1__c, Field2__c FROM Settings__c LIMIT 1;
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't be able to access custom objects in the PostInstall script? It appears to work in other places.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does your post install script have [`with sharing`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) in the class definition?

If it does, try removing it or changing to `without sharing`. There may be an issue with the user that the post install script is running as not being able to access the custom object when sharing rules are enforced.

Comment: This appears to be the case. My install script was actually a (very big and complex) legacy upgrade script that has existed for a few years, and is now being ported to the new PostInstall infrastructure. As such, there was a lot of code hitting "with sharing" sections of code.

Restructuring this so everything ran in a system context fixed the issue.